# How to fix colour of suede shoes after cleaning

Tags: cleaning, shoes

I have my suede shoes that needed to be cleaned. So I bought a cleaning kit for suede shoes, the way it said to use was to.

> Pour generous amount of liquid in a bowl full of water, dip the brush
>   in the bowl and then rub in on surface of shoe in circular motion.
>   Clean with cloth.

The problem now is that my shoe is darker then the other. Although it cleaned it well, but my first shoes I put to clean to darker in colour then the other one. Is there a way to fix my shoe colour so they match up?

Comment: Do you mean SUEDE shoes?

Comment: Yes. I will edit that.

Answer (score 1):

I clean my suede shoes with Ronsonol lighter fluid. It evaporates and doesn't leave watermarks-though I make sure to feather the edges of it when applying just in case. I don't know what the cleaner you used is but you can try to remove it with the Ronsonol and a toothbrush if there is a residue. It's about $4 and comes in a plastic yellow bottle with a fold down spout. You can get it at most corner stores. It also removes stains from clothing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a spray color for suede can do the trick? Buy the shade which is the closest to the original color of your shoes.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not clean both shoes, do the second as well, the same way and with the same amount of cleaning solution and water.

When both have been cleaned with the same method and there is still colour difference, you can try complaining in the store you bought them, as then the difference in colour may be from the factory.

Likely you can do very little about changing the colour of one shoe, without the risk of changing it too much, even when you dye the shoes you may be left with differences.

If the shoes are really different, you may try to put the darker one out in daylight or even straight sunlight.
Shoes that have been in shop windows do sometimes bleach and the pair will not match anymore. The only way to correct that is having the other out in the sun as well, but keep checking that you stop the bleaching process in time.